# JavaScriptSerializer Question

Tags: json, c#-4.0

I am having some issues DeSerializing the following Json, it runs, throws no errors however the props in the class are all null so it is obviously not working.

```
 { "realms":[ { "type":"pve", "queue":false, "status":true, "population":"medium", "name":"Malfurion", "slug":"malfurion" } ] }
```

The above JSON is the jsonResult string so string jsonResult = the above JSON

My code:

```
public class Realm
{

    public string type { get; set; }

    public bool queue { get; set; }

    public bool status { get; set; }

    public string population { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string slug { get; set; }

}
var realm = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Realm>(jsonResult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no props in the object because the object contains a single array with a single object in the array.

Comment: internal class Realm  

{  

    public string type { get; set; }  

    public bool queue { get; set; }  

    public bool status { get; set; }  

    public string population { get; set; }  

    public string name { get; set; }  

    public string slug { get; set; }  

}  

internal class RootObject  

{  

    public Realm[] realms { get; set; }  

}